Animation of Euler top
I am trying to animate the motion of the Euler top, where the ellipsoid will change its Euler angles with time. Is there a method to visualize the ellipsoid's spin, nutation, and precession motion? I use NDSolve to solve the ODE that governs the Euler top.

I think this is a very thorough notebook to get you started "The rotational dynamics of space station Mir with Euler methods" https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2594213

Could you upload code with your model? See my answer to this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/232976/tennis-racket-theorem/233021#233021
